Lỗi không hiển thị được layout viewPager
enter image description here

Mình đã kiểm tra lại đoạn mã và không tìm thấy lỗi nằm ở đâu, màn hình cũng không thông báo lỗi

Mình thực hiện theo kênh youtube này https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=63m6hXAZP74&list=PLD8zSU7U1L2GVhpPIUlJegpP8HRC2r58w&index=22

Đây là link github https://github.com/huyenmi16/LTAR


Hy vọng mọi người có thể giúp mình sửa lỗi này

https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions
